# How to create two dim array after pivot in C#

Tags: c#, linq, pivot

I'm receiving a Json doc from 3rd party which when deserialized, I have a dynamic object list in following format

```
period       key          val
"2013-3"     0            5
"2013-3"     1            6
"2013-3"     2            5  
"2013-3"     3            6
"2013-3"     4            15
"2013-3"     5            25
"2013-3"     ">5"         55
"2013-3"    "mykey1"      25
"2013-3"    "mykey2"       6
"2013-4"     0            15
"2013-4"     1            16
"2013-4"     2            25  
"2013-4"     3            36
 and so on...
```

First, I need to remove `mykey1` and `mykey2` from this data which I should be able to do using a where clause in LinQ

```
.Where(w => (string)w.key != "mykey1" && (string)w.key != "mykey2")
```

Once done, I need to pivot data with columns as key (ordered 0 to 5 and then string ">5") and get a two dimensional array `int[,]` of the values. this I have no clue as to how!

So result could be something similar as below..

```
int[,] activities= { 
                      {5,6,5,6,15,25,55},
                      {15,16,25,36,21,22,23},
                      {31,32,33,34,31,32,33},
                      {41,42,43,44,41,42,43},
                      {11,12,13,14,11,12,13},
                      {21,22,23,24,21,22,23},
                      {31,32,33,34,31,32,33},
                      {41,42,43,44,41,42,43},
                      {11,12,13,14,11,12,13},
                      {21,22,23,24,21,22,23},
                      {31,32,33,34,31,32,33},
                      {41,42,43,44,41,42,43}
                      };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(g => g.period).Select(c => new
        {
            period = c.Key,
            s0 = c.Sum(f=> f.key.ToString() == "0" ? f.val : 0),
            s1 = c.Sum(f=> f.key.ToString() == "1" ? f.val : 0),
            s2 = c.Sum(f=> f.key.ToString() == "2" ? f.val : 0),
            s3 = c.Sum(f=> f.key.ToString() == "3" ? f.val : 0),
            s4 = c.Sum(f=> f.key.ToString() == "4" ? f.val : 0),
            s5 = c.Sum(f=> f.key.ToString() == "5" ? f.val : 0),
            s6 = c.Sum(f=> f.key.ToString() == ">5" ? f.val : 0),
        })
        .ToList();
```

`result` will be like this:

```
{ period = "2013-3", s0 = 5,  s1 = 6,  s2 = 5,  s3 = 6,  s4 = 15, s5 = 25, s6 = 55 }
{ period = "2013-4", s0 = 15, s1 = 16, s2 = 25, s3 = 36, s4 = 21, s5 = 22, s6 = 23 }
...
```

---

The dynamic version can be something like this:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(g => g.period)
             .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, l =>
                list.Where(w => w.period == l.Key)
                    .GroupBy(k => k.key.ToString())
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
                    .Select(s => s.Sum(f => f.val)));
```

That returns a dictionary of period keys and list of summed values based on their keys ;).

**Edit :**

```
var result = list.GroupBy(g => g.period)
            .Select(l =>
                list.Where(w => w.period == l.Key && !w.key.In(new[] {"myKey1", "myKey2"}))
                    .GroupBy(k => k.key == ">5" ? "6" : k.key.ToString())
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
                    .Select(s => s.Sum(f => f.val))
                    .ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: You should add ">5"  in those first cases. Also, can you really order by key ? The type is dynamic.

Comment: tnx, I add it, without casting to string it will also order by ;).

Comment: Np, that dynamic version is much better than your first one haha.

Comment: Tx, but The ordering has >5 prior to 0 in case of dynamic, also I need the data in the format mentioned as I need to send in that format to frontend..

Comment: @Arnab I add a new version to support all your needs, HTH ;).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the efficiency of this but it works with any number of items per `period`. Also you get a `int[][]` instead of `int[,]`.

```
var periods = list.Select(w => w.period.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
List<int[]> matrix = new List<int[]>(periods.Count());

foreach(string p in periods) 
{
    matrix.Add(list.Where(w => w.period.ToString().Equals(p)
                   .Select(w => (int)w.val))
                   .ToArray());
}

int[][] arrays = matrix.ToArray();
```